# distribute numbers randomly in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have 40 fruits and I want to distribute it randomly and store in array of length 10.

See below code inputs.

```
var fruits = 40;
var arr = [];
```

And I want output like this
arr = [2,5,1,0,0,3,6,10,0,13];

10 positions of array should be filled randomly but addition of values should be 40.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can a particular number (other than zero) occur multiple times?

Comment: @bluefeet this does not look "too broad" to me.

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes.
The answer given by Bergi is working perfectly..

Comment: @SalmanA No obvious attempts made at solving the problem typically land questions in the too broad category.

Comment: Yeah, but the distribution isn't guaranteed to be uniform; I guess that may not be a requirement, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @bluefeet The expected output is provided, I don't see why you would consider it "too broad". The "too broad" reason is itself too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive divide-and-conquer approach:

```
function distribute(length, value) {
    if (length <= 1)
        return [value];
    var half = Math.floor(length / 2),
        dist = Math.floor(Math.random() * value);
    return distribute(half, dist).concat(distribute(length-half, value-dist));
}
```

Comment: It is giving range error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: @KhawerZeshan Are you sure you called it with a non-zero integer `length`?

Comment: Yes [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dmwkgq6/)

Comment: @KhawerZeshan Oops, I'm blind. Thanks for actually trying out the code - apparently no-one did for over 4 years! The `half` should not be computed randomly I guess.

Comment: @Bergi Is this working fine now or any better solution?

Comment: @Ayyappa Yes, it's working correctly since the edit. Whether the divide-and-conquer approach results in a distribution of values that fits for your use case I can't tell however.

Comment: @Bergi I still see "30:32 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" as per the fiddle

Comment: @Ayyappa The fiddle has not been updated of course. The answer has.

Comment: Ahh! Extremely sorry. I thought i cross checked but didn't!